# How to understand Spring for interview?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an interview tomorrow and noting I read about spring makes any sense. Anyone can help in easy to understand spring and hibernate tutorials.
I feel it's easier to code in sprint then to answer interview questions. Help

Comment: Spring and hibernate is a fairly vast area. A SO answer cannot possibly cover everything you need for an interview. Look at some slides on slideshare or videos on Youtube.

Comment: Open the documentation and scan the parts you are interested in. Nobody can answer on such a broad question :)

Answer (score 4):

> Baeldung has really added helpful content in this blog for spring
>   interview. You'll really find this link useful and other best thing is
>   that you can find all working examples as well when you open links
>   inside answers.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-interview-questions

Answer (score 3):

Spring is amazing and you're right, it's easier to code in Spring than it is to explain. I have been developing with Spring for years and I have learned the most by accidentally omitting annotations that were needed, and tracking down the errors. Don't fret - I've listed some of the most basic starting points to get familiar with. From there, venture in the direction that you're most interested in.

**Spring 101: Get familiar with this terminology**

- Annotations
- Dependency Injection
- Autowiring Dependencies

Wikipedia will have the most plain-language explanations of the above terms and may lead you to other concepts.

**Spring 102: Get familiar with these annotations**

- `@Configuration` is the starting point
- `@Bean` and `@Component` are defining modules at application start
- `@Inject` and `@Autowired` is inserting those predefined modules into another module

Check out this recent [tutorial on Spring dependency injection](http://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring)

**Spring 201: Annotations for REST API**

- `@RequestMapping` will define the PATH and HTTP METHOD for an API
  endpoint

Check out this [tutorial on building REST API in Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/building-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-and-java-based-configuration#rest)

**Spring 202: Annotations for Hibernate**

- `@Entity` to define a java object that is translated to a row in a database table
- `@Table` to define which table the entity is associated with
- `@Column` to define which column a java object variable is associated with

This is best seen by example in this [tutorial on using Spring Hibernate](https://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial)

**Finally**

- Don't feel like you need to know everything about Spring; basic concepts will get you a long way!

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Framework provides a comprehensive programming and configuration model for modern Java-based enterprise applications. 
Core support for dependency injection, transaction management, web applications, data access, messaging, testing and more.
Using spring framework, you can implement a application.
But java developer use spring framework as base framework. Usually spring will be use with struts (for MVC) and Hibernate (for database)
Using other framework (struts, Hibernate) you can reduce many work as database management and MVC management and session management.
Hibernate ORM (Hibernate in short) is an object-relational mapping tool for the Java programming language.
In code, you can get table as object array when implement query, but using hibernate you can get table entry as class.